# Where is wpa_supplicant started and how do you change config file (on Debian)?

Tags: linux, debian, wpa-supplicant

I am working with Debian. I know that wpa_supplicant is being started during boot. Where is it being started from? Also, I want to change the config file that wpa_supplicant is using. I know it's possible to start wpa_supplicant from the command line and specify a config file but how I do change this permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scripts responsible for configuring wireless network interfaces at boot are located in

```
  /etc/network/{if-pre-up.d,ip-up.d,if-down.d,if-post-down.d}
```

Each of these directories contains a *wpasupplicant* file, which is just a symbolic link to */etc/wpasupplicant/ifupdown.sh*, a script that states, in its header:

```
  #####################################################################
  ## Purpose
  # This file is executed by ifupdown in pre-up, post-up, pre-down and
  # post-down phases of network interface configuration. It allows
  # ifup(8), and ifdown(8) to manage wpa_supplicant(8) and wpa_cli(8)
  # processes running in daemon mode.
  #
  # /etc/wpa_supplicant/functions.sh is sourced by this file.
```

There is no reference to wpa_supplicant per se in this file, but the reference is in *functions.sh*, the file sourced by *wpasupplicant*. It contains the following lines:

```
  WPA_SUP_BIN="/sbin/wpa_supplicant"
  ....
  start-stop-daemon --start --oknodo $DAEMON_VERBOSITY \
  --name $WPA_SUP_PNAME --startas $WPA_SUP_BIN --pidfile $WPA_SUP_PIDFILE \
   -- $WPA_SUP_OPTIONS $WPA_SUP_CONF
  ....
  start-stop-daemon --stop --oknodo $DAEMON_VERBOSITY \
  --exec $WPA_SUP_BIN --pidfile $WPA_SUP_PIDFILE
```

These are the two calls you wish to modify.